# Работа с двумерным массивом

Tags: php, массивы

Есть массив, в котором хранятся другие массивы со значениями.
Его получаем через js. Сам массив вида `[Array[6], Array[6],... и т.д]`.

Этот массив `arr` методом `post` я передаю через ajax в пхп, где и получаю его значение `$table = $_POST['arr']`.

Вопрос в том, как добраться до конкретного элемента по ключу?
Будет ли это `$table[0][0][0]` работать для выборки самого первого элемента первого массива или обращаться к нему нужно как-то по-другому?

Мне нужно вытащить через цикл каждое значение каждого внутреннего массива

js

```
(function(){            
        function changeData(){
        var name = d.getElementById('new_name').value,
            surname = d.getElementById('new_surname').value,
            email = d.getElementById('new_email').value,
            telephone = d.getElementById('new_phone').value,
            robot = d.getElementById('spam_change').value,
            xml = eventsObj.getXmlHttp(); 

            var arr = [].map.call(document.querySelectorAll('.parent_clone'), function(block) {
              return [].map.call(block.querySelectorAll('.left_info_address'), function(inp) {
                return inp.value;
              });
            });
            console.log(arr);         
            if(name === "" || surname === "" || email === "" || (telephone === "")){            
                alert("fill the fields");                       
            }
            else {           
                xml.open("POST",path_ajax_files+"edit_personal_data.php",true);
                xml.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                xml.send("name="+encodeURIComponent(name)+
                         "&surname="+encodeURIComponent(surname)+
                         "&email="+encodeURIComponent(email)+
                         "&telephone="+encodeURIComponent(telephone)+
                         "&robot="+encodeURIComponent(robot)+
                         "&arr="+encodeURIComponent(arr));
                xml.onreadystatechange = function(){
                    if(xml.readyState === 4){
                        if(xml.status === 200){
                            if(xml.responseText !== ""){
                                alert(xml.responseText);
                                if(xml.responseText === "ok"){
                                    alert("data will be changed");                                   

                                }

                            } else {
                                alert('try again later');
                            }
                        }
                    }
                };            
            }   




        } 

        eventsObj.addEvent(saveData, "click", changeData, false);   
})();
```

PHP

```
<?php 
$table = $_POST['arr'];
var_dump($table); // выводит string вместо массива 
?>
```

`table` должен принимать массив, в данном случае он принимает строку из элементов массива `arr`.

Comment: *как добраться до конкретного элемента по ключу* - в зависимости от ваших массивов и ключей в них. Если ключи просто в порядке возрастания - от нуля и дальше - ну тогда `$table[0][0][0]`

Comment: Возникло смятение просто, если `arr` передает в пост а потом перезаписываем в `$table`  то выходит, это тот же массив только в другой переменной пхп

Comment: @ddeadlink а вы не пробовали вначале попробовать самостоятельно проверить что получается?

Comment: Посмотрите `var_dump($table)` – там могут быть как массивы, так и объекты внутри.

Comment: Всегда можно сделать `var_dump($_POST['arr'])` или `var_dump($table)` и увидеть что получилось ;)

Comment: `var_dump($table)` показывает ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12",] почему-то, а там должно хранится 2 массива

Comment: Выходит `$table` принимает строку а не массив

Comment: нужно просто что бы полученный массив в пхп файле был массивом, сейчас же переменная из `post` принимает не двумерный массив, а строку

Answer (score 0, accepted):

кому интересно - вот решение.
Раз `$_POST` принимает строку тогда в конец каждого 6го элемента ставим "/" и разбиваем по нему и по ","

```
$table = explode('/,',$_POST['arr']);
for($i = 0, $c = count($table); $i < $c; $i++) {
    $row = explode(',',$table[$i]); 
    //$row имеет значение элементов из массива `arr[i]`
}
```

Comment: Если Ваш ответ является решением Вашего вопроса, пожалуйста отметьте его решением(зеленая галка под цифрой слева от ответа).

Answer (score 0):

При отправке массива в POST-запрос вы фильтруете массив функцией `encodeURIComponent()`, которая возвращает строковое представление.

Если нужно передать массив из JS в PHP, можно воспользоваться представлением его в JSON с последующим восстановлением на стороне PHP.

То есть на стороне браузера должно быть примерно так:

```
'&arr=' + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(arr));
```

А на стороне сервера

```
$table = json_decode($_POST['arr'], TRUE);
```